# Using MatSelect with rxjs fromEvent events not being heard? (selectionChange)

Tags: angular, events, rxjs, angular-material

I am trying to get the value from a MatSelect, using rxjs fromEvent. I can't get it to pick up that an event has happened though. I have it working with MatInput, because I think that inherits default behaviour from the Html input element, but something is different with MatSelect.

If I swap out mat-select for a default select, the (change) event is picked up and it works as intended.
(change) was apparently deprecated at some point on MatSelect, and no longer works.

I've tried moving the template ID to the mat-option to see if it could pick up an event from there, no luck.
tried:
(change)
(select)
(selectionChange)
(valueChange)

```
 @ViewChild('projectNameInput', {static: false, read: ElementRef}) projectNameInput: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('pipelineSelect', {static: false, read: ElementRef}) pipelineSelect: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('codeCoverageInput', {static: false, read: ElementRef}) codeCoverageInput: ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   // server-side search
   const projectObs$ = fromEvent(this.projectNameInput.nativeElement, 'keyup');
   const selectObs$ = fromEvent(this.pipelineSelect.nativeElement, 'onSelectionChange');
   const coverageObs$ = fromEvent(this.codeCoverageInput.nativeElement, 'keyup');

   const all$ = merge(projectObs$, selectObs$, coverageObs$)
     .pipe(
       debounceTime(300),
       distinctUntilChanged(),
       tap(() => {
         this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
         this.loadSummariesPage();
       })
     )
     .subscribe();

   this.paginator.page
     .pipe(
       tap(() => this.loadSummariesPage())
     )
     .subscribe();
 }

------------------------------------

 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>types</mat-label>
   <mat-select name="type" [(ngModel)]="type">
     <mat-option #x *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
       {{option.viewValue}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `Observable` you need to subscribe to it if you want to receive stream data.

In your component code you need something like:

```
selectObs$.subscribe(selectedVal => console.log(selectedVal));
```

**note**: Remeber to unsubscribe in the `OnDestroy` component event, to prevent memory leaks.

**UPDATE**

1 - In your component you should bind the matSelect and not the matOption. Then you can listen to the selectionChange emitter (like an Observable):

```
 @ViewChild(MatSelect) select: MatSelect;
```

Without the need of #x in the template altogether.

2 - Have you tried to change the line from:

```
const selectObs$ = fromEvent(this.pipelineSelect.nativeElement, 'onSelectionChange');
```

to

```
const selectObs$ = fromEvent(this.pipelineSelect.nativeElement, 'selectionChange');
```

I have never worked with the nativeElement's event, but matSelect has an EvenEmitter `selectionChange: EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>`, so it might be a naming mismatch.

3- use selectionChange emitter:

```
<mat-select name="type" [(ngModel)]="type">
     <mat-option #x (selectionChange)="onValueSelected()" *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
       {{option.viewValue}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

Comment: Sorry I omitted that, I do have it subscribed to, I have merged three observables and subsribed to that. As mentioned, if I swap out MatSelect for a standard select , it works just fine.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. Could you paste your full code, or at least how do you use the observables together and the subscription?

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work for me though unfortunately.  I got a console error something along the lines of invalid event target.

Comment: Can you create a simple stackblitz sample? This way it will be easier to debug it.

Comment: I tried what you suggested above, creating a method that was called as a result of the (selectionChange) event, and just grabbed the value from there, and I got the value I was looking for. Would still like to have been able to do it via fromEvent, This gets me what I want for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @ViewChild('selectCaselaod') selectCaselaod: MatSelect;
  @ViewChild('inputUniqueId') inputUniqueId: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('inputName') inputName: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('inputLastName') inputLastName: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('selectStatus') selectStatus: MatSelect;
        
  merge(
    fromEvent(this.inputName.nativeElement, 'keyup'),
    fromEvent(this.inputLastName.nativeElement, 'keyup'),
    fromEvent(this.inputUniqueId.nativeElement, 'keyup'),
    this.selectCaselaod.valueChange,
    this.selectStatus.valueChange
  ).pipe(
    debounceTime(150),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => {
                this.paginator.pageIndex = this.pageIndex;
                this.loadApplicationsPage();
              })
        ).subscribe();
```

Comment: valueChange EventEmitter worked for me...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add few lines to explain your solution...